# P4 command to fetch swarm review id?

Tags: perforce, p4v, swarm

Can someone please help with the perforce (p4v) command to fetch Swarm review id corresponding to a change list for which swarm review is raised already.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the review for a change with the swarm api:
https://www.perforce.com/manuals/swarm/Content/Swarm/swarm-apidoc_endpoint_reviews.html#Get_List_of_Reviews

There's no p4vjs method if that was what you were asking.

Comment: In Perforce there is a column Review id . I need to fetch that review id field corresponding to a shelved cl for which swarm review is already raised. If review is not raised , review id field will be empty for that particular shelved cl.

Comment: Right.  P4V calls the swarm api to get that:

Comment: For example, change 31:

http://swarm/api/v9/reviews/?fields=id,changes,stateLabel&change[]=31

Parse the return json.  
{"lastSeen":32,"reviews":[{"id":32,"changes":[31,33],"stateLabel":"Needs Review"}],"totalCount":1}

the reviews id column is your review - in this case 32.  There may be more than one review for the change.